# Approaches to a Dynamic Pathfinding Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, d-star

My A* implementation works well for my static environment.
If I would now like to work with a dynamic environment, i.e. certain costs between my nodes change while we are traversing from the start to the finish.

From my reading so far I have found the LPA*, D* and D* Lite algorithm that could help me. Well my worst case scenario would be to implement all and see what works best.

**Is there any research done on comparing the capabilities of these algorithms?** 
The papers that I have read so far just focus on a single algorithm at a time and since their experiment environments are different, it is hard to make a comparison.

**Some background information: I'm using C++ and my environment is a 3d scene with my search graph being represented using navmeshes.

Comment: See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this paper](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/RDR/media/iros07-final.pdf) could help you, **Reactive Deformation Roadmaps: Motion Planning of Multiple Robots in Dynamic Environments** by
*Russell Gayle Avneesh Sud Ming C. Lin Dinesh Manocha*; The abstract goes like this:

> We present a novel algorithm for
> motion planning of multiple robots
> amongst dynamic obstacles. Our
> approach is based on a new roadmap
> representation that uses deformable
> links and dynamically retracts to
> capture the connectivity of the free
> space. We use Newtonian Physics and
> Hooke’s Law to update the position of
> the milestones and deform the links in
> response to the motion of other robots
> and the obstacles. Based on this
> roadmap representation, we describe
> our planning algorithms that can
> compute collision-free paths for tens
> of robots in complex dynamic
> environments.

They present an algorithm that is physically-based, adaptive roadmap
representation that retracts and changes its topology as a
function of the dynamic environment. Iit can be used
to plan the motion of a single robot or multiple robots among
**dynamic obstacles**.

Answer (score 2):

It's been some time since you asked, so maybe you've already had time to try them all... But for what it's worth, the D*-Lite paper (http://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2002/AAAI02-072.pdf) has a section at the end, *Experimental results*, comparing performance with LPA*, D* and A*.